# Binding object property to UserControl DP error

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am having trouble with a binding on this UserControl `aph:FilterItemControl`

The Filter object has properties: Negate, Valued and MatchCase. The first and last bind just fine, however `Valued` does not.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type helpers:Filter}">
    <Grid x:Name="FilterGrid" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ToggleButton x:Name="NegationButton" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Negate}"
                      Content="!"
                      Grid.Column="0" />

        <aph:FilterItemControl x:Name="FilterValueTbx" 
                               ToolTip="{Binding Valued}"
                               ValueType="{Binding CurrentPropertyFilter.PropertyType, Source={x:Static helpers:MyClass.Instance} }"
                               Grid.Column="1" />

        <ToggleButton x:Name="MatchCaseToggle" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding MatchCase}"
                      Content="Aa"
                      Grid.Column="2" >
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :
>   BindingExpression path error:
>   'Valued' property not found on 'object' ''FilterItemControl'
>   (Name='UserControl')'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Valued;
>   DataItem='FilterItemControl' (Name='UserControl');
>   target element is
>   'FilterItemControl' (Name='UserControl');
>   target property is
>   'ToolTip' (type 'Object')

Just wondering why and how I can fix this?

It looks like it's jumping to the DataContext of the UserControl, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach into the data context of a parent element by using this syntax:

```
  {Binding Path=PathToProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}}
```

In your example you would use the following:

```
{Binding DataContext.Valued, 
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                             AncestorType=Grid}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like it's jumping to the DataContext of the UserControl, why?

If you don't provide a binding source it will bind to `DataContext` of that element. My best guess is that you change the `DataContext` of the `aph:FilterItemControl` internally in the control.

Comment: I do I thought it would only affect the internals of the UserControl not the exterior binding, so that's interesting!

Comment: If you want only to effect the elements inside the `UserControl` set the data context on Content of `UserControl`.